How do I make an HTML radio button form change the value in another box?
I am trying to make a rubric using radio buttons. So far, I have a form with radio buttons and a section at the top for the grade. I'm wondering if there is a way to program the grade section to automatically fill in with the percent of how many "GO" buttons are clicked.
I know the form looks a little wonky right now, but that was done quickly to adjust for showing what I'm talking about.
I'm pretty new to HTML and I feel like all of my Googling attempts have been fruitless thus far. Hopefully someone can help me out. Or tell me I'm just plain wrong and steer me in the right direction.


You can do that with pure HTML and CSS but it going to be a mess. The cleaner solution would be to use JS. Is that an option for you?

Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>] and provide a [mcve]

I didn't give any attention to the styling as this is not a question of styling. You can change the style as you need.
You need to run a script whenever an input change within the container that contains all the "things" changes. That can be done by using addEventListener.
Next you need to count the amount of "things" you have. That I have done by counting the containers of the "Go/No-Go" sets with querySelectorAll and length.
After that you need to count the length of the selected "Go"s by using the methods again. The CSS selector for that is: [value="Go"]:checked.
Last, you need to calculate the percentage by dividing the amount of the selected "GO"s by the amount of sets. You can use a progressbar or an output to display within your HTML document.


PerformancePoints.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // count the amount of Go/No-Go sets
  const ThingSetLength = this.querySelectorAll('fieldset').length;

  // count the amount of selected GOs
  const SelectedGoLength = this.querySelectorAll('[value="Go"]:checked').length;

  // calculate percentage of selected GOs
  const PercentageGo = (SelectedGoLength / ThingSetLength * 100).toFixed(2);

  // output the percentage
  ProgressGo.value = PercentageGo;
})
progress {
  text-align: center;
  &::after {
    content: attr(value)'%';
  }
}
<div id="PerformancePoints">

  <label for="ProgressGo">Grade</label>
  <progress min="0" max="100" value="0" id="ProgressGo"></progress>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Thing 1</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="GoThingA" name="ThingA" value="Go">
      <label for="GoThingA">Go</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="NoGoThingA" name="ThingA" value="NoGo">
      <label for="NoGoThingA">No-Go</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Thing 2</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="GoThingB" name="ThingB" value="Go">
      <label for="GoThingB">Go</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="NoGoThingB" name="ThingB" value="NoGo">
      <label for="NoGoThingB">No-Go</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Thing 3</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="GoThingC" name="ThingC" value="Go">
      <label for="GoThingC">Go</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="NoGoThingC" name="ThingC" value="NoGo">
      <label for="NoGoThingC">No-Go</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>




Or even this ;) PerformancePoints.addEventListener('change', function() { const ThingSet = [...this.querySelectorAll('[value="Go"]')]; ProgressGo.value = (ThingSet.reduce((acc, rad) => acc + rad.checked, 0) / ThingSet.length * 100).toFixed(2); });

It can be done with some JavaScript. You'll need to select the HTML elements for where the percentage value goes, the form, and all of the radio inputs marked "Go". Then you can assign an anonymous function to the onchange property of the form element, count the number of "Go" inputs that are selected (their checked property will be set to true), then do the math and assign the result to the innerText property of the element for the percentage value.
This example does what you want:


let gradeElement = document.querySelector('#grade')
let formElement = document.querySelector('#form')
let goInputElements = document.querySelectorAll('[value="go"]')
let totalGoInputs = goInputElements.length

formElement.onchange = function() {
  let checkedGoInputs = 0
  for (input of goInputElements)
    if (input.checked) checkedGoInputs++
      let grade = Math.round((checkedGoInputs / totalGoInputs) * 100)
  gradeElement.innerText = grade
}
<h1>Grade Calculator</h1>
<h2>Grade = <span id="grade">0</span>%</h2>
<form id="form" action="#">
  <section>
    <h3>Thing 1</h3>
    <p><input type="radio" name="thing-1" value="go" /> Go</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="thing-1" value="no-go" /> No-Go</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Thing 2</h3>
    <p><input type="radio" name="thing-2" value="go" /> Go</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="thing-2" value="no-go" /> No-Go</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Thing 3</h3>
    <p><input type="radio" name="thing-3" value="go" /> Go</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="thing-3" value="no-go" /> No-Go</p>
  </section>
</form>




you should not use onchange but rather addEventListener. onchange overwrites every other onchange event while addEventListener will append an event. Instead of using a for loop to count the elements with [value="go"] you could simply use [value="go"]:checked. <p> is for flow text. It is not a suitable container for input elements and certainly not a container trying to give meaning to an input. For accessibility reasons a label has to be used!

@tacoshy All true, and I would not write my code exactly that way, but I was trying to keep the example simple and easy to read, as the author of this question stated "I'm pretty new to HTML". My example was not meant to show best practices, only to demonstrate how it can be done without getting too complicated. Why did you edit my answer? That seems to make it unclear where the first fenced block of code should be written.

I moved your code to a runable snippet that does not require the head element. When posting code you should always use a [repro] and pay extra attention to the word minimal. Don't write in-depth answers to broad questions, teaching every simple basic. Users are expected to do their own research effort. You ask questions and answer them on SO not with a single user in mind but to help the community as a whole with specific on-topic questions and answers. Expect that others might have the same issue which otherwise would have to dig out the important bits of a long text.
